# How to filter and eliminate duplicates values in querysets?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have table like this in Django + postgres:

```
____________________
| room_id | user_id |
|--------------------
| 1       | 100     |
| 1       | 101     |
| 2       | 100     |
| 2       | 102     |
| 3       | 103     |
 ...
```

Each `room_id` can be duplicated only 1 time. I need to figure out `room_id` where to users are.
Simple way:

```
user_id_1 = 100
user_id_2 = 101
rooms = Room.objects.filter(users__in=[user_id_1, user_id_2])
temp = []
for room in rooms:
    if room.id in temp:
        room_id = room.id
        break
    else:
        temp.append(room.id)
```

But is there any sql filter way?

Comment: Use `.distinct()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) and [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to do this beautifully.

```
rooms = Room.objects.filter(users__in=[user_id_1, user_id_2])\
            .distinct("room_id").values_list("room_id", flat=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `distinct(<field name>)` method

```
rooms = Room.objects.filter(users__in=[user_id_1, user_id_2]).distinct('users')
```